# Getting an error message when executing a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard using event.keyCode ===13

Tags: keyboard, passwords, enter, keycode

I'm trying to create a function that allows users to press enter on their keyboards to validate a password field.  I keep getting page not found message when the password is wrong after hitting enter on the keyboard.  If I click the enter button on the password box my alert pops up and nothing happens ,as intended.  I basically want the same exact result from clicking the enter button on the  keyboard.  How can I get this to work properly?

Below is a link to the Pen I am currently trying to work with.

https://codepen.io/Pacman0006/pen/LYbqQYa

```js
//creates a funtion that validates password
function computerPassword() {
var val = document.getElementById('password').value;
if (val =="Joker") {
  window.open("https://www.google.com");
  //location.href="https://www.google.com";
}else{
  //keep getting errors so I added this 
  //to open in same window when user inputs wrong after hitting enter
  //window.open("https://www.bing.com", "_parent");
 alert("that is the wrong password");
}
}

var input = document.getElementById("password");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard; from W3Schools.com
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("go").click();
         }
});
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light","Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
  color:white;
  font-size:12px;
  background:#333 url(/images/classy_fabric.png);
}

form {
    background:#111; 
  width:300px;
  margin:30px auto;
  border-radius:0.4em;
  border:1px solid #191919;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

form:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:1px;
  width:100px;
  left:20%;
  background:linear-gradient(left, #111, #444, #b6b6b8, #444, #111);
  top:0;
}

form:before {
    content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:8px;
  height:5px;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:34%;
  top:-7px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px #fff;
}

.inset {
    padding:20px; 
  border-top:1px solid #19191a;
}

form h1 {
  font-size:18px;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 black;
  text-align:center;
  padding:15px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position:relative;
}

form h1:after {
    content:"";
  display:block;
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50px;
  pointer-events:none;
  transform:rotate(70deg);
  background:linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.15), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  
}

label {
    color:#666;
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:9px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    width:100%;
  padding:8px 5px;
  background:linear-gradient(#1f2124, #27292c);
  border:1px solid #222;
  box-shadow:
    0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius:0.3em;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

label[for=remember]{
    color:white;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom:0;
  padding-top:5px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.p-container {
    padding:0 20px 20px 20px; 
}

.p-container:after {
    clear:both;
  display:table;
  content:"";
}

.p-container span {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#0d93ff;
  padding-top:8px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 20px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius:0.3em;
  background:#0184ff;
  color:white;
  float:right;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:13px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

input[type=text]:hover,
input[type=password]:hover,
label:hover ~ input[type=text],
label:hover ~ input[type=password] {
    background:#27292c;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Input Your Password</h1>
  <div class="inset">
 
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </p>
  
  </div>
  <p class="p-container">
    
    <input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="Enter" onclick="computerPassword();">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I figured out the problem.  Lonny B mentioned posting a Form to a server which I had no intention of doing.  However, it got me thinking that a form element by nature may be looking for this server without me explicitly telling it to.  Whether it is or isn't Im not entirely sure but I changed the form element to a Div in my html and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a syntax error/a missing `{`. Give this a shot:

```
//creates a funtion that validates password
function computerPassword() {
var val = document.getElementById('password').value;
if (val =="Joker"){
  window.open("https://www.google.com");
  //location.href="https://www.google.com";
}else{
  //keep getting errors so I added this 
  //to open in same window when user inputs wrong after hitting enter
  //window.open("https://www.bing.com", "_parent");
 window.open("https://bing.com"); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Well that was a silly mistake.  Thanks for fix.  It is now opening the new window. 
However, I'm still getting the error message on the original page "Page not Found".  I would prefer not have to resort to redirecting to a new url every time someone enters the wrong password with the keyboard.  I'm self taught and trying to learn as I go.  Is there a better way to do this?  I would prefer the page to do nothing when the password is entered wrong with the enter key.

Comment: No problem, it happens. I'm not sure what you want to do if the password is wrong but if you want to show a message that says "wrong password..." then you could hide/show a div by creating a css class with display:none in it. If the password is wrong, remove the class that hides the div with the error in it so that it shows. Otherwise, do something with the right password. In a real world scenario, you'd  POST a form to the server with the credentials in it so that an API could validate them against a database.

Comment: Ill try that.  I'm steering clear of API's. Im a school teacher and Im trying to create virtual locks for activities I do in class.  For some reason the school issued computers would not fetch the database but my computers at home would.  I'm not sure why but I'm sure whatever the reason it was above my head so i just put the code in the script directly.  I feel like what I want it to do is  simple enough yet somehow is so complicated.  My plan or thoughts were, when the user enters the wrong password and hit enter on the keyboard nothing would happen and the current url would stay the same.

Comment: instead it It opens a new page that says page not found.  Thanks to your help I can at least direct the page to a working url but what I really want is it to stay the same so the user can keep trying to input the password.